# Get a container to scale to the browser window size in em's

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a container `div` that I'd like to scale to size according to the size of the browser window on load. I'm using `em`'s for heights and widths.

This is what I've got but I don't know why it isn't working:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var windowwidth = $(window).width();
    var windowheight = $(window).height();
    var bodyfontsize = $('body').css(font - size);

    var adjustedwidth = (1 / bodyfontsize) * windowwidth;
    var adjustedheight = (1 / bodyfontsize) * windowheight;

    $('#container').width(adjustedwidth 'em').height(adjustedheight 'em');
});
```

What am I doing wrong and what should I do to fix this?

Comment: Can't you just use a percentage size in CSS?

Comment: concatenate `adjustedwidth+'em'`

Comment: Dynamic resizing can be done with CSS.  What are your intended results?  jQuery might be overkill for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: What would be the purpose of using ems if the element's dimensions are relative to the browser window?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var windowwidth = $(window).width();
    var windowheight = $(window).height();
    var bodyfontsize = $('body').css("font-size").replace("px", "");

    var adjustedwidth = (1 / bodyfontsize) * windowwidth;
    var adjustedheight = (1 / bodyfontsize) * windowheight;

    $('#container').width(adjustedwidth + 'em').height(adjustedheight + 'em');
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jonnysooter/v8EJd/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Use pixels instead for width and height. I have never used em for anything else than font sizes.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var windowwidth = $(window).width();
    var windowheight = $(window).height();

    var adjustedwidth = windowwidth;
    var adjustedheight = windowheight;

    $('#container').width(adjustedwidth).height(adjustedheight);
});
```

Comment: `px` is restrictive, `em` is fluid. You should be using `em`.

Comment: @JonnySooter Why?  The unit you use doesn't matter if the element is being sized relative to the viewport.  I agree that the "use pixels for height/width" comment is either naive or unclear as to whether they mean *in this situation* or *always*.

Comment: Well, by strictly using ems, everything becomes relative. Therefore, it's easier to adapt to different situations. For example media queries. If I used ems from the start, I would just have to update one main reference selector and the page would follow suit. By using `px`, I would have to update every `px` reference and do math to make sure it's proportionate.

Comment: The idea was to hold the page in a container which fits the users full browser window, stay that size if the browser is resized but also if a user inceases their text size, the container will icrease in size too, majority of the elements in the container are percentages.

Comment: It may of been a rookie mistake, it just occured to me that i might not of included the jquery file.. I will have to check tomorrow.